# Dojo/Dijit Trial and Error

Tags: debugging, dojo

I've been trying to get [this page](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html?theme=soria) to run on my machine under Google App Engine.  One file at a time, I think I have found all the missing files, and .gifs, and layouts, etc..., and now have them on my machine and being served properly.  No more critical errors as observed from FireBug.

Here are the differences between my test and the page mentioned above - and I don't have a clue as to why:

1. The pull down menu with File/Edit/View/Help etc... is above the left "AccordionContainer".
2. The accordion container is not acting like an accordion.  Every section is open, and I can only see the first section and about 1/2 of the second one.
3. The accordion tab/titles have a +- to the left, for example: +-Popups and Alerts and right justified is a little circle with an arrow pointing left (where on the "real" sample page, the little circle is left of the title, and either points right or down depending on whether that box is open or not).
4. The entire upper right and lower right containers are white, but there is a blue divider line between them.
5. If I grab and move the blue bar separating the left according container from the right containers, the tool tips quit working, as well as anything I click on.

I really want to use Dojo - but I'm not sure I'm learning - but rather just poking with trial and error. When things don't show up where they are supposed to be - I'm not sure which clues to follow to figure it out. CSScss files, the Javascript itself?  Where do I start?

Things that are working at first:

1. Tooltips
2. the ShowModal Dialog and Show Tooltip Dialog
3. The tree structure for the countries seems to be working
4. The pull down menu works

Another StackOverflow question - can I post a follow-up when someone answers?  I click "comment" and "answer your question" and nothing happens?  Is that because I'm such a new user to StackOverflow?

Thanks to all.
Neal Walters

Neal Update - 6:44pm Central Time

I now have my web page public accessible - if anyone wants to try it with FireBug:
http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijit

I cannot seem to reply to Seth below - so I will reply here.  I did have some CSS that were missing, but fixed them, and now it seems like they are all there - but exact same results - as you can see in URL above.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though there's a CSS file missing.  Does the Firebug net tab show any 404 errors for CSS?

Regarding learning dojo, it's a big library.  Early on, it's kind of rough going.  Dojocampus is a good resource and the forums were before spammers killed them off.  People seem to have migrated to here and/or [the mailing list](http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/mailman/listinfo/dojo-interest).  IRC is also a good place to get quick answers.  It's `#dojo` on freenode.

About the stackoverflow questions, I saw some of your comments on other questions. Was it somewhere specific that was missing?  I don't think you can answer your own question until 24 hours has passed. What you usually want to do is 'accept' one of the answers given by other people (like me!).  If that's not the right answer, you should post it on [meta.stackoverflow.com](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for you input!  I have posted web page here: http://3wcloud-com-provisioning-qa.appspot.com/testDijit.  I also posted on IRC - but no takers yet.  All CSS now seem to be loading.

Answer (score 0):

Wow - I am amazed!  The problem was because I was loading the soria.css from AOL/CDN.

I made this switch:

Commented out this:

> <link id="themeStyles"
>   rel="stylesheet" 
>             href="http://o.aolcdn.com/dojo/1.1/dijit/themes/soria/soria.css">

Replaced with this:

> <link id="themeStyles"
>   rel="stylesheet" 
>             href="/stylesheets/dojoThemes/soria/soria.css">

and it worked!  What a waste of my afternoon!

The first issue was that sometimes in Firebug - it was show no data for the soria.css, and the left side of the page would lose its blue boxes.  So sometimes the css was loading, sometimes it wasn't - about 80/20.  It was driving me crazy because I could press F5 to refresh and it might work or might not. So that's one reason I switched to a local copy.

Then this link also gave me encouragement to switch: 
http://www.dojotoolkit.org/forum/dijit-dijit-0-9/dijit-support/unable-run-my-editor-aol-or-google-cdn.  Supposedly it's an old bug that was fixed, but maybe it sneaked back in?

Neal

Comment: That's odd.  It could also be because you were using an old version of the stylesheet (note the `1.1` in the url).  The dojo version you are running is 1.3.2 (which you can get by entering `dojo.version` in the console).